# Construct() must be an instance in symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, object

I wanted to build my own `__construct` for calling my `TaskListRepository` but it doesn't work:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\TaskListRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;

class ListController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{

    /**
     * @var string $taskListRepository
     */
    private $taskListRepository;

    public function __construct(TaskListRepository $taskListRepository)
    {
        $this->taskListRepository = $taskListRepository;
    }

    public function getListsAction()
    {
        return $this->taskListRepository->findAll();
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\TaskList;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method TaskList|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method TaskList|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method TaskList[]    findAll()
 * @method TaskList[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class TaskListRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, TaskList::class);
    }  
    //commented lines removed for readability  
}
```

Error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\ListController::__construct() must be an instance of
>   App\Repository\TaskListRepository, none given, called in /data/ 
>       applis/GIE/var/cache/dev/ContainerAfvn1yx/getListControllerService.php
>   on line 14

Comment: This is symfony3.4, you still have to define arguments in `services.yml`. And I'm not sure that controller can be service in symfony3.

Comment: @u_mulder - autowire was introduced in 3.2 and is pretty much standard in 3.4 unless you are bringing along a legacy app.  Being able to define controllers as services goes all the way back to 2.0 though few people did so.  Not sure what is wrong here.  The error message confirms the controller is being pulled from the container.  Might be as simple as clearing the cache.  The OP should consider posting the relevant portions of the services file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have enabled `autowiring` for you controllers or configure controller as service explicitly. In your case `TaskListRepository` should be a service too.